# Complete Web designing for beginner from HTML to server side programming

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, dhtml

I'm a beginner and I started with the HTML document and in between the document I moved to Java script to understand the document properly and from Java Script to OOPs in Java script. Now I have become so confused about what to do.I'm reading all the stuff from downloaded tutorials to on-line tutorials like echoecho, w3c and tutorialspoint. I want to learn everything about web designing so can anyone suggest me where to start so that I don't mingle all stuff. Please suggest me some books or tutorials to start and what to follow next. 
I'm interested in learning HTML, Javascript, CSS, DHTML and XML.

Comment: stop reading and just start building some websites. you'll never hold all that information in your head unless you start putting it to use. think of a small project you might find enjoyable, and then build that. eventually you'll hit a road block and you'll have to research how to solve it. that's how you learn. (or how i learn best anyway)

Answer (score 3):

There are 8 Tutorial videos provided by Google to help someone learn HTML, CSS, and Javascript!

It includes the following:

1. Introduction
2. HTML
3. HTML Excercise
4. CSS
5. CSS Walkthrough
6. CSS Exercise
7. Javascript
8. Javascript Excercise

Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

I learnt HTML, CSS, JS and XML by a combination of reading W3C tutorials and building my own sites. All the reading in the world won't help you unless you actually have a go.

You should look at these languages in order, working on at least one project for each:

HTML ~ Content

CSS ~ Styling

JS ~ Interactivity

XML ~ Data manipulation

PHP ~ Dynamism

So the first project might for a static site that only uses HTML, the next might just be that same site but made prettier with styles. Then you get to XML and you might do something like a music archive site. Etc, etc.

If you hit a problem don't leave it (unless you're sure its too advanced for you), search forums and post questions on stackoverflow until you find the solution. Screwing up is essential to learning! You can use the developer's console in your browser (I like Internet Explorer 9's) to find out what's going wrong as well.

I would also recommend you work in [Web Matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/). Using files in a folder will only get you so far, whereas Web Matrix supports using XML, PHP and Razor code exactly like a real server would.

EDIT:

I forget to mention....    Envy is very good! If you see something on the internet and think "how the hell did they do that?" you should see if you can recreate it or at least look through the source code to see how it works. All the best engineers pulled apart watches when they were kids.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to learn basic tags
like html,body,title,script,a,input,button,iframe,div etc...

Then learn css and master how to position,color,align,resize them.

You can learn the basic of these two in a day.

Next comes javascript. if you know the basics of any programming language,then you can skip a lot of things. 
The power and beauty  of js lies in DOM manipulation.Go for DOM manipulation and events. Its is pretty confusing in the beginning. Learn java script debugging, else it will kill you.
Don't go ahead without mastering DOM and events.
(html,css and javascript)= dhtml. DHTML is not a separate thing.

Once you master DOM, them you will automatically understand XML. Because DOM itself is XML. Well you must learn xml name space and xpath too (But practically xml is waste if you don't know ajax)

If you are comfortable with all the above things, then you will take 10 mins to learn ajax.

Answer (score 0):

imo you should learn HTML & CSS first... creating some templates for CMSs (like joomla, wordpress).. it's important to understand the basics!

after that you could start adding some functional things with javascript. you'll never get what "DOM scripting" is without the basics..

at this point you can also learn some HTML5 cause its (imo) the future of the web =)

//EDIT:
if you like to learn something about the way to build a website from scratch take a look here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/12/14/web-strategy-guidelines-building-a-website-from-start-to-finish/

one of the best sites you can collect some informations is http://w3schools.com/

Comment: Thought I better jump in with http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score -1):

You need to stop reading every tutorial. What you need to do is practice... I am also a web designer and providing online training courses. I know how to handle my students when they get confused. Confusion arises due to too much information available on the web. So first start with one topic, i.e. HTML.

1. Intro
2. HTML Basics
3. HTML Elements
4. HTML Attributes and so on.

you can also prefer visiting this [**Software Training**](http://www.softwarejobstraining.com)

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Comment: Please also note that answering such questions with just an ad for your own product is borderline spam.